# How to make the instances scale to follow the base curve tangent?

Tags: geometry-nodes

So I have this horizontal curve where I'm instancing spirals from. I grab the tangent of the curve and scale the instances oriented from that vector but it doesn't work as expected. How to procede so the scaling in X and Y occur perpendicularly to the curve's splines? Thx!

[image]

PS: The tangent from the 'curve to points' node is the original curve's tangent right?

[image]

Comment: maybe uneven scale is the issue. Try to apply scale

Comment: no, it's all good already

Comment: Can you share the file then?

Comment: Not sure what you're after here.  The tangent of the curve is just a direction.  It may be a vector, but it's a normalized vector; its length is always 1.  It represents the direction that a curve is travelling, and that's not a concept where magnitude means anything.  Separating components isn't really meaningful either; you're getting a portion of the vector based on your object axes.  Do you want instead to rotate them to match the tangent?

Comment: Crantisz: I can't share this one file, but I can assemble this nodes.  Nathan: I have an array of circular shapes and I don't want to scale them from Z axis, This is already going as expected, whats not right is this strange behaviour of the spirals squeezing. Is there a way of performing this squeeze perpedicularly to the curve tangent?

Comment: Please make a sketch of what you want. It seems you don't understand how scaling works in Blender, and that what you're really after is aligning first, and then scaling. Potentially, you may want to realize instances and then deform the 'spirals' (they look like circles to me)

Comment: Hello Markus! Indeed, I don't know how scaling works apparently. I've been struggling with a lot of stuff lately trying to make a cool asset, tryng to juice  some intelligence out. The reason why they seem circles is because they are seen from above in isometric view to better illustrate my problem. I'm will try realizing the instances.

Comment: The instancing is with 0 rotation (_not_ aligned to the curve). The scaling _is_ aligned to the curve. Each instance will be stretched in a different direction with respect to its own geometry. Maybe you want to align the instances to the curve, first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I get it! What was getting in the way was that 'Curve to Points' node, I just replaced to 'Resample Curve' so I didn't lose the info from the original curve - this somehow was screwing up the tangent information. Thanks for your time guys! Peace out! =)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is how you scale along a custom axis in Blender:

[image]

*Transform Geometry* nodes use matrix transformations (in all cases except when only *Translating* = moving), and this is the typical matrix shenanigans (just like rotating around a custom pivot points means moving so the pivot point is in the origin, rotating, and moving back). Just keep in mind since you don't have the super-convenient "Reverse" option known from the *Vector Rotate* node, if you rotate on more than one axis, you need to manually reverse the rotation order from $xyz$ to $zyx$:

[image]

In your case you want to rotate multiple things, so You can't use the *Transform* node, but you can use equivalent instance nodes:

[image]

The result, as well as a comparison with UV spheres:

[image]

### Aligning scale to tangent

I think you might be after this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Um, wicked! I obtained a non-deformed result up there but the thing is that the won't align properly. Has it to do with that? My impression is that I'm not capturing precisely the tanget's perpendicular vector.

Comment: @AAAYerus I forgot to ping you to see the edit, so, see the edit and if it's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The best result I achieved so far has been this one, but as you can see it's still not aligning perfectly to the perpendicular. As you can see, I grabbed the perpendicular of the base curve's tangent, the spirals are kind of aligning to it but badly. Anything I can do to improve?

[image]